# FreeBSD nullfs and strange file size

Tags: filesystems, freebsd

How to determine a correct file size? It cannot be 680G. I suppose it's somehow related to some `nullfs` related feature

```
# ls -lah system.log
-rw-r-----  1 web  vuser   680G 21 Jul 22:59 system.log

# du -hs
25G

# df -hT .
Filesystem                    Type      Size    Used   Avail Capacity Mounted on
/usr/local/www/apache24/data  nullfs    181G     61G    120G    34   [restricted]
```

Server uses ZFS:

```
# mount
vsd/myhost on / (zfs, NFS exported, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)

# zfs list -o name,mountpoint,used,logicalused,compression
NAME        MOUNTPOINT         USED  LUSED  COMPRESS
vsd         /home/vsd         75.6G  80.6G       lz4
vsd/myhost  /home/vsd/myhost  74.5G  78.4G       lz4
```

Comment: Could you please share output of "mount" command? Do you use ZFS? if yes, could you please share output of "zfs list -o name,mountpoint,used,logicalused,compression"?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just a [sparse file](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). A file with holes in it (unused blocks that when read return zeroes). Usually, you can look up how many blocks it uses with

```
ls -ls system.log
```

Comment: That is a possibility but quite unusual for a log file though.

Comment: @Martin Sugioarto: Julie Pelletier is right. No, it's not a sparse file as it's written by web application. Sparse files are for disc images (created by virtualization software).

Comment: No. Sparse files on Unix-like systems can be generated when seek is used and then some data is written beyond the end of file. Of course, I might be wrong, but it's still possible that log files are sparse by accident. When you miscalculate the initial seek (and log files need to be appended, of course), it might cause a hole in the file. It's easy to check, by the way, because log files typically don't store zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

If it's nullfs, then take a look at the "target" file?

Comment: The "target" file is `/usr/local/www/apache24/data/system.log`, but I don't understand how it can have that high size.

Comment: if it's ZFS (or fs with compression), it's possible. :)

Comment: ZFS example: # ls -lah unbound.log => 263G # du -sxh . => 12G